# Can anyone tell me what this means?

Tags: meaning

[image]

My aunt sent this symbol/emblem to my brother which comes from our japanese side of the family. But I would like to know what it actually means.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to JSE. Unfortunately, as described here: https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-se/799#799, we typically don't do translation or lookup requests without some indication of prior research on the part of the person asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly 齋{さい}藤{とう} : Saitō (Japanese surname)